# MySQL Left Join throwing off my count numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a left join on a table to get the number of leads we've generated today and how many times we've called those leads. I figured a left join would be the best thing to do, so I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(rad.phone_number) as lead_number, rals.lead_source_name as source, COUNT(racl.phone_number) as calls, SUM(case when racl.contacted = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as contacted
FROM reporting_app_data rad 
LEFT JOIN reporting_app_call_logs racl ON rad.phone_number = racl.phone_number, reporting_app_lead_sources rals
WHERE DATE(rad.created_at) = CURDATE() AND rals.list_id = rad.lead_source
GROUP BY rad.lead_source;
```

But the problem with that, is that if in the `reporting_app_call_logs` table, there are multiple entries for the same phone number (so a phone number has been called multiple times that day), the lead_number (which I want to count how many leads were generated on the current day grouped by lead_source) equals how many calls there are. So the count from the LEFT table equals the count from the RIGHT table.

**How do I write a SQL query that gets the number of leads and the total number of calls per lead source?**

Comment: if you don't give us sample data and expected results you will never get any help I think

Comment: Why are you using old style joins with the rals table?

Comment: Try `COUNT(DISTINCT expression)`

Comment: @AllenKing The COUNT(DISTINCT rad.phone_number) worked!! I'd loved to give you the answer!!!!

Comment: @AdamMcGurk answered :-)

Comment: Your problem is probably the cross join not the outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `COUNT(DISTINCT expression)`

In other words, change `COUNT(rad.phone_number)`  to `COUNT(DISTINCT rad.phone_number)`